# WP_Query a custom field value bringing back 0 results

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop

I am trying to do a query to grab all the pages that have the tickbox checked `"feature_on_front_page"` which has the value `"featured"` with label `"Featured"`.

I added this checkbox with ACF.

My query is:

```
        <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
        <?php

        // args
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'meta_key'      => 'feature_on_front_page',
            'meta_value'    => 'featured'
        );


        // query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>
        <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                       do some stuff
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

It brings back 0 results.  I looked in database and the `"feature_on_front_page"` key has data value `"a:1:{i:0;s:8:"featured";}"`

I have tried using array instead of string but I can't work out exactly what I am doing wrong

I tried:

```
'meta_value'    => array('Featured' => 'featured')
```

and

```
'meta_value'    => array('featured')
```

and various other variations.  I know this is simple but I can't see where I am going wrong.

Here is what it looks like in database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Ok this should work, according to ACF's documentation:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'feature_on_front_page',
            'value'     => 'featured',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    )
);
```

---

Your code works for me.

Can you see the `feature_on_front_page` custom field when you view the page(s) in the WordPress admin area?

Or perhaps the problem lies in the `do some stuff` section you've omitted?

Comment: Yes, I have gone into pages, ticked the box and then saved as ACF makes you create a fieldset so I am not sure if its nested somehow?  I think the issue is the way the value is stored in database "a:1:{i:0;s:8:"featured";}" and not just a simple string but I am not sure.

Comment: Ah yes it looks as if ACF stores the value as a serialized array. Try `'meta_value' => 'a:1:{i:0;s:8:"featured";}'` - pretty ugly hack I know :)

Comment: Yeah this works so its obviously the way I'm accessing it.  What is proper way as this doesn't appear in any example I have looked at

Comment: I'm not familiar with ACF but is there a way to specify that the custom field `feature_on_front_page` should be a simple boolean (true or false) rather than an array?

Comment: See my update above

Comment: Yep you got it, ping me for coffee :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23210/discussion-between-guerrilla-and-sqrbrkt).

Answer (score -1):

Try "posts_per_page" in place of "numberposts". numberposts is not a valid parameter of WP_Query.

if you are using "ACF", then I think this will not work with WP_Query. This is not logical but I had same kind of bad experience. Try once

Comment: I've been trying to follow the documentation here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ . Changing to posts_per_page and also removing it do not work.

Comment: Your stored value has no problem, it's a serialized data. try adding wp_reset_postdata() after endwhile not after endif. Everything else looks okay to me..